# PDFlib - trimming pages

Tags: pdflib

I am trying to figure out whether it's possible to trim a PDFlib page AFTER its dimensions have been set.

For example, I have a non-standard page that is 500x10000pt:

```php
$p->begin_page_ext(500, 10000, '');

...

$p->end_page_ext('');
```

After I'm done adding elements to it, I will know how tall that page should be.

How can I trim that page to the height of 2000pt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
How can I trim that page to the height of 2000pt?
```

by simple using:

`$p->end_page_ext('width=500 height=2000');`

It's just important that this will reduce the page dimension from the origin (lower left). Otherwiese you might use the `cropBox` Option to crop the page to some special area. For example:

`$p->end_page_ext('cropbox={100 100 600 2100}');`

Please see PDFlib 9.2 API Reference, chapter 3.3 for details for all option of end_page_ext().